# sql query with create command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a problem in creating a table from another table.
I am using the query:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as ( SELECT Distinct * FROM old-table)
```

Its giving the error

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Distinct * INTO new_table 
FROM old-table 
GROUP BY whatever you want to group by
```

EDIT: You can cast the rows to Varchar, which is comparable, or you can group by the column values that you want to be distinct.

Comment: its giving the error as: The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: Instead of all, do this to your columns
CAST(TEXT_COL AS VARCHAR(MAX))

Comment: If you want to keep all the data, go into "Design mode" in your table, choose a comparable type, like INT or VARCHAR instead of text and **Group by** that column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`select ... into`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx):

```
select  distinct * 
into    new_table
from    old_table
```

Comment: its giving the error as:     The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: but I need the distinct rows

Comment: @smriti: Which version of SQL Server are you using?  Could you add the column list of old_table?

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (yourcolumn) as Row,  * 
INTO new_table 
FROM old-table 

DELETE FROM new_table where Row > 1
```

OR

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (yourcolumn) as Row,  * 
INTO new_table 
FROM old-table 
WHERE Row = 1
```

Cant DISTINCT over ntext. Otherwise create your table first with a varchar and add a unique index with ignore duplicates on and cast on the insert. You may lose data if longer than your column though so watch out.

Could do an xml conversion into the other table then filter and manipulate as you wish but the first two are what I would probably recommend.

Comment: it is giving error around (yourcolumn) as:   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: can u suggest anything else?